# Error when copying files to an existing folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing some code that prompts the user to add a folder name, then copies all the files on the CD drive (D:) to `C:\Example\ & FolderName` if it doesn't already exist.

The code works until I try to copy files to a folder that already exists then I get a `Run-time error 70: Permission Denied`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Sub CopyFiles()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim FileExt As String
Dim FNames As String
Dim FolderName As String

FolderName = InputBox(Prompt:="Your folder name", Title:="Folder Name", default:="Folder Name here")

If Dir("C:\Example\" & FolderName & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir "C:\Example\" & FolderName
Else
End If

FromPath = "D:\"
ToPath = "C:\Example\" & FolderName & "\"
FileExt = "*.flac*"

If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    FromPath = FromPath & "\"
End If

FNames = Dir(FromPath & FileExt)
If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files in " & FromPath
    Exit Sub
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `MkDir "P:\Example\" & FolderName` be `MkDir "C:\Example\" & FolderName`

Comment: To avoid such errors, define a variable at the top which will contain the path and then you can use that variable where ever you want. And if next time you have to change the value, you will have to do it at only one place...

Comment: Yes, @SiddharthRout my fault. I was just changing the code to something generic from my actual drives so I'll fix that in the question. The problem still exists, although I will take your advice to create a variable that `=C:\Example\`

Comment: Do You have Rights to that folder?

Comment: Yes, I can create a folder, edit, and delete it in that directory.

Comment: The code has no errors creating the folder if it doesn't exist and copying all the files into that folder. The problem arises when I try to copy all the files from a new CD to that same folder.

Comment: let me test it... one moment

Comment: Your code worked for me...

Comment: Interesting. So if you gave the FolderName a value of "Test1", copy files, then give the FolderName a value of "Test1" again, the second round of files were added to that folder?

Comment: The problem is i think you have not defined your query well :) And I realized this from your last comment. You will get a permission denied error if the same files are already present in the folder and not because the folder exists :)

Comment: See my reply. You may have to refresh the page.

Comment: BTW, instead of FSO you can use DIR / FileCopy / [Setattr](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/HV080557569.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that the folder exists. The problem is that you are trying to copy files and overwrite them

Overwriting is usually not a problem but fails if the files in the destination folder have `Read Only` Attributes. You can read more about it in this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

What happened was when you first copied the files from the CD Drive, the file which where copied retained the Read Only Property. You can check that by Right Clicking on the File and checking their properties.

To overcome this problem, you need to reset the file attributes or delete the files in that folder.

To delete, you can simply use

```
On Error Resume Next
Kill "C:\MyFolder\*.*"
On Error GoTo 0
```

To change the attributes, you have to loop through the file and check if their property is read only. You can do that by

```
If fso.GetFile(Dest_File).Attributes And 1 Then
```

and to reset it, you have to use

```
fso.GetFile(Dest_File).Attributes = fso.GetFile(Dest_File).Attributes - 1
```

Once you do that you will be able to copy the files across.

Answer (score 0):

As Siddharth mentioned, the error occurs because the code is trying to overwrite existing files. So, if you don't want to overwrite the files, you can simply add a If Error Resume Next. The solution code I am using is below:

```
Public Sub CopyFiles()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim FileExt As String
Dim FNames As String
Dim FolderName As String

FolderName = InputBox(Prompt:="Your folder name", Title:="Folder Name", default:="Folder Name here")

If Dir("C:\Example\" & FolderName & "\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir "C:\Example\" & FolderName
Else
End If

FromPath = "D:\"
ToPath = "C:\Example\" & FolderName & "\"
FileExt = "*.flac*"

If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    FromPath = FromPath & "\"
End If

FNames = Dir(FromPath & FileExt)
If Len(FNames) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files in " & FromPath
Exit Sub
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

On Error Resume Next

FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean `On Error` and not `If Error` :p